# How to call a function several times in C++ with different parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

I have the next code:

```
object a,b,c;
fun (a);
fun (b);
fun (c);
```

I wonder if it is there any way to do something similar in C++98 or C++11 to:

```
call_fun_with (fun, a, b, c);
```

Thanks

Comment: You could quite easily write that yourself, using a function pointer, or functor for the first parameter.

Comment: Put in [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)?

Comment: That is an option, but I wonder if there is a already some feature in C++ to deal with that

Comment: @VicenteAdolfoBoleaSánchez, there is: put the sequence of inputs in a vector and use std::for_each (as JoachimPileborg said). That is _the_ canonical way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the following using variadic template:

```
template <typename F, typename...Ts>
void fun(F f, Ts&&...args)
{
    int dummy[] = {0, (f(std::forward<Ts>(args)), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // remove warning for unused variable
}
```

or in C++17, with folding expression:

```
template <typename F, typename...Ts>
void fun(F&& f, Ts&&...args)
{
    (static_cast<void>(f(std::forward<Ts>(args))), ...);
}
```

Now, test it:

```
void foo(int value) { std::cout << value << " "; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fun(foo, 42, 53, 65);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: The nice part is that this even works when `foo` is overloaded and/or cnversions are nededed: `void foo(int); void foo(std::string); fun(foo, 42, "abc", 3.5);` - will call `foo(std::string("abc"))`

Comment: @Jarod42 You should read the comments on that page, the void cast is not a portable way to disable the warning http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/

Comment: @MSalters: It will? I'm intrigued. Please tell me how. ;)

Comment: @MSalters: Um, no, not really, because to pass `foo` in to `fun` you already need to have picked an overload: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dfa11bb6692eee8

Comment: @MSalters what's `F` in that call to `fun`?

Comment: It may works if F is a *Functor* as in `struct foo { void operator () (int) const; void operator () (const std::string&) const; };`.

Comment: Eh, thinko there. The "conversions" part is correct, even if the conversions needed differ per agument. I then added the "overload" without thinking it through. I blame the flu.

Comment: @Jarod42: I think it even works, including all the overloading, with `struct FunctorFoo { template<typename T> auto operator(T t) const -> decltype(foo(t)) { return foo(t); } };`

Comment: @MSalters: use perfect forwarding: `T&&t` and `std::forward<T>(t)`.

Answer (score 7):

Here a variadic template solution.

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename f_>
void fun( f_&& f ) {}

template < typename f_, typename head_, typename... args_>
void fun( f_ f, head_&& head, args_&&... args) {
    f( std::forward<head_>(head) );
    fun( std::forward<f_>(f), std::forward<args_>(args)... );
}

void foo( int v ) {
    std::cout << v << " ";
}

int main() {
  int a{1}, b{2}, c{3};
  fun(foo, a, b, c );
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote you (since your solution has no overhead), but you're using illegal identifiers. Anything which contains a double underscore is reserved for the compiler and standard library.

Comment: @Angew was sure it was only at the beginning of the identifier, fixed.

Comment: Note to Visual Studio users, you need at least VS2013 to use Varadic Templates

Comment: @benjymous Or VS2012 with the November CTP.

Comment: At the beginning it's underscore followed by uppercase letter, and in the global namespace also just underscore. Two underscores are reserved anywhere. Anyway, uvpoted :-)

Answer (score 5):

Using C++ 11, you can use `std::function`, this way (which is quite quick to write IMO)

```
void call_fun_with(std::function<void(int)> fun, std::vector<int>& args){
    for(int& arg : args){
        fun(arg);
    }
}
```

or, a bit more generic:

```
template<typename FTYPE>
void call_fun_with(FTYPE fun, std::vector<int>& args){
    for(int& arg : args){
        fun(arg);
    }
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc31345467a395a1)

[**Live example, templated version**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78437ec85803934d)

Note: `std::function` template arguments must be specified the following way: `return_type(arg1_type, arg2_type,etc.)`

**EDIT**: An alternative could be using `std::for_each` which actually does pretty much the same thing, but which I do not really like as to the semantics, which are more like "for everything in this container, do...". But that's just me and my (maybe silly) way of coding :)

Comment: Thats a great solution, Thanks for replying! :D

Comment: Why are you taking the function as a `std::function`, instead of using a template parameter? Even when you don't have variadic templates, accepting the function type as a template parameter makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @MSalters Well because to be frankly honest I don't really feel comfortable with that. Sure, [**this works**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78437ec85803934d) though I'm not sure this would be the correct way to do it with a template parameter.

Comment: @JBL: That's indeed what I was thinking, can't see what would be wrong with that.

Answer (score 2):

A C++11 range-based (enhanced) for loop will recognise a *braced-init-list* as an `initializer_list`, which means something like the following will work:

```
for (auto &x : {a,b,c}) fun(x);
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. The only downside is that it doesn't generalise to mixed-type parameters, which is a shame.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of different way's...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void foo(int x) {
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}

void call_fun_with(std::function<void(int)> fn, std::vector<int> lst) {
    for(auto it : lst)
      fn(it);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> val = {1,2,3,4,5};

    // c++98
    std::for_each(val.begin(), val.end(), foo);

    // c++11
    // vector
    call_fun_with(foo, val);

    // c++11
    // initializer_list
    int a=0, b=1, c=2;
    call_fun_with(foo, {a,b,c});
}
```

see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04f35e6bf6e5b932).

Comment: This answer may be the most complete. Thanks!!