# Template function pointer as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, c++14

I define a set of function templates:

```
template < typename type >
void foo ( type object )
{
    //  foo the object
}

template < typename type >
void bar ( type object )
{
    //  bar the object
}

template < typename type >
void baz ( type object )
{
    //  baz the object
}
```

Now I want to define a function template which takes a pointer to any of the functions from the above.

```
    template < /* ??? */ , typename T , typename... TT >
    void for_each ( T parameter , TT... other parameters )
    {
       // process the first parameter using the function pointer defined by the first template parameter
       // recursice call to for_each
    }
```

What is the correct way to declare the first template parameter?

**P.S. I do know that there is a workaround to wrap the first three functions each in a class and make them static. I just want to know if there is a straight way to solve the problem.**

Comment: if you don't care about `type` inside `for_each()`, then it's simply,`template<typename F, typename... TT> void for_each(F f, TT... other)`

Comment: Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21454613/2694444

Comment: @Kolyunya Could you add a hypothesis use case to the question ?

Comment: @galop1n the use case is explicitly defined in the question - processing of the heterogeneous variadic parameter packs.

Comment: @Kolyunya You're attempting to compile it as C.

Comment: Then there is no solution, you can only have template classes in template arguments, and not template functions. This is because function have overload resolution, a better system than template specialization.

Comment: @Nim could you please provide an example since I could not manage to compile your snippet http://ideone.com/dF4CKs Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct foo_overload_set_t {
  template<typename... Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&... ts) const
  -> decltype( foo(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) ) {
      return ( foo(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) );
  }
};
static const foo_overload_set_t foo_overload_set;
```

now `foo_overload_set` is a single object which can be treated like a function, and when invoked does overload resolution on the function `foo` based off the passed in parameters.

Ie, `foo( a, b, c, d, e )` runs the same code and gives the exact same result as `foo_overload_set( a, b, c, d, e )` for any set of arguments.

But `foo_overload_set` is an object, while `foo` is an indeterminate set of functions created on the fly based off parameters used to call it.

We can pass said object to your `for_each`:

```
template<typename OverloadSet>
void for_each( OverloadSet ) {} // do nothing

template < typename OverloadSet , typename T , typename... TT >
void for_each ( OverloadSet overload, T&& parameter , TT&&... other_parameters )
{
   overload( std::forward<T>(parameter) );
   for_each( overload, std::forward<TT>(other_parameters)... );
}
```

invoked like:

```
for_each( foo_overload_set, a, b, c, d, e );
```

which proceeds to call `foo` on `a`, then on `b`, then on `c`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Template template parameters can only be class templates, not function templates, so you'd have to wrap the function template in a class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo_wrap {
    static constexpr void (*fn)(T) = &foo<T>;
};
```

In C++1y you might consider streamlining this with a generic lambda, although that would be a function parameter, not a template parameter:

```
for_each(..., [](auto t) { foo(t); }, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

template template arguments have to be classes.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T> void ignore( T... ) {}

template < template < typename T > class f_, typename... args_>
void fun( args_&&... args) {
    int dummy[] { ( f_<args_>{}( std::forward<args_>(args) ), 0)...};
    ignore(dummy);
}

template < typename T > 
struct bar {
    void operator()( T v )  const {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
};

int main() {
  int a{1}, b{2}, c{3};
  float d{4.5};
  fun<bar>(a, b, c, d );
}
```